# Starling Particle Effect

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am developing an app in AS3 which utilizes the starling particle extension but I am have some trouble not looping it.

I created a new class in an objects package called particle which has the below code in it.

```
mParticleSystem = mParticleSystems.shift();
mParticleSystems.push(mParticleSystem);
mParticleSystem.emitterX = 320;
mParticleSystem.emitterY = 240;
mParticleSystem.start();
addChild(mParticleSystem);
Starling.juggler.add(mParticleSystem);
```

I call this class in my main project by

```
particle = new Particle();
this.addChild(particle);
```

Everything works perfectly except I am unable to stop the juggler. I have tried adding an event listener onto the mParticleSystem and call a function to remove but the event doesn't fire. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your variable `mParticleSystem` is an instance of the class `starling.extensions.ParticleSystem`. In this case, `ParticleSystem` objects dispatch an Event "complete" when they have finished emitting all particles. You can check this [Quick Tip: Starling Particle Effect Disposal](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3189) by the great Lee Brimelow with the actual code (the updated working code is at the very beginning).

Another nice option is that you can specify for how long you want your `ParticleSystem` to emit your particles for by passing a parameter to its `start()` method:

```
// emit particles for two seconds, then stop
mParticlesSystem.start(2.0);
```

So then you can remove your `ParticleSystem` from the juggler after 2 seconds.

Hope this helps!